# django implement filter on in template

Tags: python, html, mysql, django

i m buiding an in terface (something like phpmyadmin) but more userfriendly...i ve imported all tables but now i want to add sort,filter and search on every table.

this is my tables/views.py

```
def table_base(request):
    table_name = Crawledtables._meta.db_table
    list_tables = Crawledtables.objects.order_by('id')
    return render(request, 'tables/table_base.html', {'table_name': table_name,
                                                      'list_tables': list_tables})


class AboutDetail(DetailView):
    model = Crawledtables
    pk_url_kwarg = 'table_id'
    template_name = 'tables/table_list.html'

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AboutDetail, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def get_object(self):
        if 'table_id' not in self.kwargs:
            return Crawledtables.objects.get(id=1)
        else:
            return Crawledtables.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['table_id'])


def addview(request, table_id):
    table_name = Crawledtables.objects.get(id=table_id)

    tbl_details = "SELECT * FROM " + table_name.name
    tbl_detail = AllTables.objects.raw(tbl_details)

    paginator = Paginator(list(tbl_detail), 100)
    page = request.GET.get('page')

    try:
        details = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        details = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        details = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    crawled_tables = AllTablesFilter(request.GET, queryset=tbl_detail)
    return render(request, 'tables/table_list.html', {'tbl_name': table_name,
                                                      'details': tbl_detail,
                                                      'filter': crawled_tables,
                                                      'detail_page': details})


def GeneralSearch(request):
    table_list = Crawledtables.objects.all()
    crawled_tables = GeneralFilter(request.GET, queryset=table_list)
    return render(request, 'tables/table_search.html', {'filter': crawled_tables})


def AllTablesSearch(request, table_id):
    table_name = Crawledtables.objects.get(id=table_id)

    tbl_details = "SELECT * FROM " + table_name.name

    table_list = AllTables.objects.raw(tbl_details)
    # table_list = Crawledtables.objects.all()
    crawled_tables = AllTablesFilter(request.GET, queryset=table_list)
    return render(request, 'tables/alltables_search.html', {'tbl_name': table_name,
                                                            'filter': crawled_tables})
```

this is my tables/filter.py

```
class GeneralFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Crawledtables
        fields = ['name', 'date']


class AllTablesFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = AllTables
        fields = ['id','title', 'url','description']
```

and my table_list.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    {% load app_filter %}

<br>

    <h1> {{tbl_name|split:"_"}} {{ tbl_name.date|split:"-" }} Data</h1>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Url</th>
        <th>Descriptions</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
        {% for lists in details %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ lists.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ lists.title }}</td>
                <td><a href="{{ lists.url }}" target="_blank">{{ lists.url }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ lists.description }}</td>
            </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>

{% if detail_page.has_other_pages %}
  <ul class="pagination">
    {% if detail_page.has_previous %}
      <li><a href="?page={{ detail_page.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% for i in detail_page.paginator.page_range %}
      {% if detail_page.number == i %}
        <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
      {% else %}
        <li><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if detail_page.has_next %}
      <li><a href="?page={{ detail_page.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}


{% endblock %}
```

i want to have sort, filter and search in this template, that will be a dynamic for all tables that i have. (all tables have same structure)

i did create a separate search template...but that was just for testing

Thank you in advance for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you need to write the , `filters`, `search` and `sort` in views after getting the **objects** and then you need to pass in template.

Offcourse, there are bultin functions for all these `search`, `sort` and `filters` but you need to process them in views.

**django template tags**

There are template tags for other things which serves various purposes. You can have a look on [Django Bultin Template Tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/).

Comment: should i write the filter, search and sort in the same function ( addview) and then when i render .. i also include those 3 things...or do i create a new function with only those 3 things separte and call the same template as the function addview?

Comment: You can do the both way till the time you do it correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the cooperation. You can upvote  my answer if you like.